# Jquery no conflict not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is sort of a two question into one. I'm trying to use the jquery no conflict but I don't think I'm doing it correctly.

**This is wat I have:**

> // ******************************** PLUGINS ********************************

```
jQuery.noConflict() // return `$` to it's previous "owner"
(function($){ // in here you're assured that `$ == jQuery`

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox(); /*LIGHTBOX*/
});

$(window).scroll(function(){ /*SCROLL TO TOP*/
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
    }
}); 

$('.scrollup').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    return false;
});

$('.bxslider').bxSlider();

});
```

Am i not doing it right?


*

Also, when I add this it makes everything stop working which is why I think I'n not adding the no conflict correctly:

*

> // ******************************** HEADER SHADOW ********************************

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('header').css({
                'box-shadow': 'none',
                '-moz-box-shadow' : 'none',
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : 'none' });
    }
    else {
        $('header').css({
                'box-shadow': '0px 10px 10px #888',
                '-moz-box-shadow' : '0px 10px 10px #888',
                '-webkit-box-shadow' : '0px 10px 10px #888' });
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you say "add this", you mean inside the block `(function($){ })(jQuery)` or after ? EDIT : following Robert's answer I see you just forgot to pass `jQuery`...

Comment: In the same block, so it's all one thing. 
For the purpose of this question it's shwoing separate but I was just copying and pasting under the $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass jQuery in to you function:

```
jQuery.noConflict() // return `$` to it's previous "owner"
(function($){ // in here you're assured that `$ == jQuery`

    // Code

})(jQuery); //Do you mean to pass jQuery like this perhaps?
```

Comment: I apologize in advance. I just don't really know much jquery.
When it's all together should it be like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/dffernandez/n38mE/

So, I was missing the (jQuery); at the end?

Comment: Yes you need to pass jQuery to the parameter called $ to you function. Any progress?

Comment: Perfect. It all works now. Let me ask this though
Can I combine the "Header shadow code" with The "scroll to top" since they both start the same or It's correct as it's?
This is what I ended with: http://jsfiddle.net/dffernandez/n38mE/3/

Comment: Of course you can put them in the same scroll event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/NNMw4/