# jquery croppie plugin stopping the "$(window).resize" functions from my jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery Croppie plugin "http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/" to crop the images before uploading and it works fine, but it's stopping the "$(window).resize" functions from my jquery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when jQuery events are stopped, it is usually because they have conflicts with other similaes, to avoid this use The jQuery.noConflict() Method

Replace $ with the variable, you can use it in other events, but keep in mind the change to replace $(...)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jqy = jQuery.noConflict();
jqy(window).on("load", function(){
   jqy("p").text("jQuery is working :)");
});
</script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: it worked, but with this answer method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940623/jquery-no-conflict-not-working

Comment: I used it but it making bootstrap jquery ruined